# How to send intent data to Javascript from ReactActivity of React Native

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, android-intent, react-native

I want to send intent value to Java Script from ReactActivity of React Native.

I write following example code.
How to send "tag" to JavaScript

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   Intent intent = getIntent();
   Tag tag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    // I want to send tag data to Javascript
    // How to do?
 }
```

Comment: did you find the solution? I've the exact same problem. Take a look at these :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41672759/react-native-android-app-opened-with-intent-pass-data-to-javascript

Comment: and this one :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615851/react-native-android-nfc-getting-card-id

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomActivity extends ReactActivity {

@Override
protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "CustomJSScene";
}

@Override
protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {

        @javax.annotation.Nullable
        @Override
        protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
            Bundle initialProps = new Bundle()
            initialProps.putString("key", "value");
            return initialProps;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Is that Override Method will return the data what we want to send???? then how to call that Override method from React Js?????

Comment: @Ramaraju getLaunchOptions() function will be invoked self if you will extend your activity with ReactActivity. You need not to call this function from JS.

Comment: as it was the override method it will invoke by it self that i know, but my question is How can i get the value that was returning in this method into my React JS file.... As of my knowledge, we can get data from module with help of @ReactMethod, likewise how can i get value from that Method.... Thank you.

Comment: @Ramaraju `<Text>{this.props.YOUR_PROP_KEY}</Text>` you can receive it like this in your js component.